# Adding lines using geom_segment on multiple plots with data from a list of DFs

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2, lapply

I'm trying to add multiple lines to a saved ggplot object. The coordinates for the lines are stored on a list of dataframes, one data frame for each individual plot. I successfully have created multiple plots using lapply, however, the code fails when calling the geom_segment. Below example data and code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)
#Dataframes
m.slen <- iris[,c(1,5)]
m.swid <- iris[,c(2,5)]
m.plen <- iris[,c(3,5)]
m.pwid <- iris[,c(4,5)]
#List of dataframes
m.list = list(m.slen = m.slen,
              m.swid = m.swid,
              m.plen = m.plen,
              m.pwid = m.pwid)
#Setting col names
m.list <- lapply(m.list, setNames, nm = c("data", "species"))
#Creating list of data frames with coordinates for geom_segment
meanV = lapply(m.list, function(x) mean(x$data, na.rm = TRUE))
coordy1 = lapply(m.list, function(x) x %>%
                     group_by(species) %>%
                     summarise(max = max(data, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
                     pull(max) + 2)
#Table with dynamic values
line.plot <- list()
for(i in 1:4) {
line.plot[[i]] <-
    tibble(x1 = meanV[[i]],
           x2 = meanV[[i]]+1,
           y1 = coordy1[[i]][1],
           y2 = coordy1[[i]][1])
               }
#Creating first set of plots, using first list of DFs
plots <- lapply(m.list,function(x)
    p <- ggplot(x, aes( x= data, fill = species)) +
          geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
          ggtitle(names(m.list)))
print(plots)

#Adding segments using second list of DFs
final_plots <- lapply(plots,function(x)
     plots +  geom_segment(data = line.plot,
                       aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2)))
```

Everything works until the last step, I get the following error

> Error in `fortify()`: ! `data` must be a data frame, or other
> object coercible by `fortify()`, not a list

Any input or advice is welcome. Thanks

Comment: `line.plot` may not be a good name for list of tibbles and why `for` here and not `lapply` like other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `line.plot` is a list. To achieve your desired result you could use `purrr::map2` to loop over both your list of plots and the list of dataframes for the segments:

Note: I also added `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_segment` because otherwise you will get an error, too.

```
final_plots <- purrr::map2(plots, line.plot, function(x, y) {
  x + geom_segment(
    data = y,
    aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2), inherit.aes = FALSE
  )
})

final_plots[[1]]
```

[image]

**EDIT** Using base R you could achieve the same result with `mapply`:

```
final_plots <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  x + geom_segment(
    data = y,
    aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2), inherit.aes = FALSE
  )
}, x = plots, y = line.plot, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

or thanks to the comment by @Parfait using `Map`:

```
final_plots <- Map(function(x, y) {
  x + geom_segment(
    data = y,
    aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2), inherit.aes = FALSE
  )
}, x = plots, y = line.plot)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any idea if it's possible using lapply? just to keep using base R

Comment: If you want to stick with base R you could use `mapply`. See my edit.

Comment: And `mapply` w/ `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` = `Map`

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. Much appreciated. Started R with the `tidyverse`. Still much to learn about base R. (:

Comment: Curious why OP asks to keep in base R but everything else is tidyverse including list of tibbles and not data frames. For maintainability, stick to one flavor with data handling usually `base`,  `tidy`, or `data.table`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Much appreciated. Yes, I wanted to stick with base as much as possible, I'm trying to learn base but sometimes I use whatever it works first, and then iterate. just FYI I changed to data.frame from tibble and it seems I got the same results. I also managed to do the same —adding lines— using a for loop.